# Prove that $\alpha(t)$ lies on a sphere.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\alpha(t)$ be a regular curve. Suppose there is a point $a$ in $R^3$ such that $\alpha(t)-a$ is orthogonal to $T(t)$ for all t. Prove that $\alpha(t)$ lies on a sphere.

So, I let $\alpha(t)=(x(t), y(t),z(t))$ and $a=(a,b,c)$.

Since, $\alpha(t)-a$ is orthogonal to $T(t)$,

$<\alpha(t)-a,T(t)>=0$.

But I don't know how to solve this..

Comment: what is $T(t)$?

Comment: @TsemoAristide $T(t)=\alpha'(t)$, clearly.

Comment: @JooE Compute the derivative of  $\|\alpha(t)-a\|^2$

Comment: @SphericalTriangle Actually, it should be $\frac{1}{\lVert \alpha'(t)\rVert}\alpha'(t)$, because it does not state that the curve is in arclength parametrization. Not that it matters too much.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Clearly, you don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle I admit I am quite rusty on my Frenet-frame-stuff. However, I am rather sure that the notation in, say, Shifrin's book was like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that $T(t)=\alpha'(t)$, then compute the derivative of $\|\alpha(t)-a\|^2$, it is $2<\alpha(t)-a,\alpha'(t)>$.

Comment: I solved it! Thank you :)